# tweepy --> how detect type of <class 'tweepy.models.User'> -

Tags: python, object, twitter, tweepy

I need to know the type of the variable, but this is me being unable to determine how to make the comparison

like this:

```
if temp==  <class 'tweepy.models.Status'>:


favorited --> <type 'bool'>
contributors --> <type 'NoneType'>
truncated --> <type 'bool'>
text --> <type 'unicode'>
source_url --> <type 'str'>
possibly_sensitive --> <type 'bool'>
is_quote_status --> <type 'bool'>
in_reply_to_status_id --> <type 'NoneType'>
user --> <class 'tweepy.models.User'>
geo --> <type 'NoneType'>
id --> <type 'long'>
favorite_count --> <type 'int'>
lang --> <type 'str'>
retweeted_status --> <class 'tweepy.models.Status'>
entities --> <type 'dict'>
created_at --> <type 'datetime.datetime'>
author --> <class 'tweepy.models.User'>
retweeted --> <type 'bool'>
coordinates --> <type 'NoneType'>
in_reply_to_user_id_str --> <type 'NoneType'>
source --> <type 'str'>
in_reply_to_status_id_str --> <type 'NoneType'>
in_reply_to_screen_name --> <type 'NoneType'>
in_reply_to_user_id --> <type 'NoneType'>
extended_entities --> <type 'dict'>
place --> <type 'NoneType'>
retweet_count --> <type 'int'>
id_str --> <type 'str'>
```

insurance is simple, it would help me if possible help you .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, what you want is `if type(temp) is tweepy.models.Status:`, instead of `if temp==  <class 'tweepy.models.Status'>:`

Answer (score 1):

well, python types are comparable singletons, so

```
if type(A) == type(B):
    ...
```

will work excellently.

Also

```
if type(object_of_yours) == tweepy.models.Status:
    ...
```

will work.